# .NET Core Linked Server SQL not recognized

Tags: .net, sql-server, linked-server

I am having an issue troubleshooting what is wrong with this linked server that I set up in SQL.

This is what my setup looks like in SSMS

[image]

I am able to query things successfully inside SSMS like this

```
SELECT *
From [96.86.222.9].[8903_Interchange].dbo.Carline
```

However, when I am trying to run the project inside Visual Studio 2022.  I am getting errors like this

[image]

So the first thing I did was go and check if the server was inside `sys.servers` as directed like this `select * from sys.sysservers` and it does return a result

and the stored procedure in question looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInt_ListMakes]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM [96.86.222.9].[8903_Interchange].dbo.Manufacturer
END
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: The language a client is written in doesn't affect a server's configuration. You may be using the wrong server name, connecting to the wrong server or using an account that has no permission to use the linked server

Comment: Are you sure your app is talking to the same server as you're connected to in SSMS?

Comment: How can I check? The host, username, pass are identical in SSMS and my appsettings.json

Comment: When i run `select * from sys.sysservers` there is a column called `isremote` set to 0.  Could that be the issue?